# How to get Prometheus Alertmanager alarms via API?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Is it possible to get Prometheus Alertmanager alarms via API get method?

I know about the webhook integration, but is it possible to receive these alarms with an API?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alertmanager's [API](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager#api) for that.

To get list of all alerts you can use `/api/v1/alerts`.

But be advised not to use it as replacement for webhooks to push notifications: this API is for viewing current state and alternative clients.

If you need need to adapter to push notifications to some unsupported receiver use of webhooks is advisable.